# A4 page too small

Tags: css

So I'm trying to print (CTRL+P) a page. I have all the resets I need, so I don't need to worry about margin or padding around my document. However, I simply cannot get the size to match an A4 page. Here's what I have tried:

```
@media print {
    .page {
        height: 297mm;
        width: 210mm;
        margin: 30mm 10mm;
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        height: 297mm;
        width: 210mm;
        margin: 30mm 10mm;
    }    
}
```

I have also tried simply doing:

```
.page {
    height: 297mm;
    width: 210mm;
    margin: 30mm 10mm;
}
```

But all of these simply won't make my print fit. When I throw a `border: 1px solid #000` on my `.page` element, the page is pretty much 50% of the A4 page.

What I want to achieve is: I have 1-many `.page` elements. No matter how many there are, I NEVER want to print an empty page (like if one page suddenly is 1px too tall). How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: In CSS (at least in default box model), margins are added to width and height. So you end up with 10 + 210 + 10, etc.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes that is correct. How would I ensure it's A4 no matter what? I can throw on an `overflow: hidden;` just to ensure, but setting the page size is my number one priority.

Comment: Set width to 190px?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález 1190px?

Comment: @MortenMoulder - Nope, 190**mm**

Comment: @enhzflep Why would I set the width to 190mm, when 210mm is too small and isn't correct? Where do you get the 190mm from? An A4 page is 210mm wide.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I obviously meant mm.

Comment: @MortenMoulder - never crossed this bridge myself, hence my interest. (I just write directly to a pdf with php) I just tried to provide what seemed to be the intended answer.

Comment: My comment was only meant as that, a comment, and I only tried to explain that you need to start with the right figures and then troubleshoot stuff. CSS that tries to accomodate to a 23 centrimetre sheet perhaps is not the best starting point (for instance, the browser will need to make it smaller if it needs to fix in A4).

Comment: @enhzflep No offense, but why would 190mm ever be the intended answer, when 190mm isn't anywhere near the correct size? I've gotten 1190x1683 pixels to work.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález What do you mean? 23 centimetre? Where did you get 23 centimetre from?

Comment: 23 comes [from here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=(10+%2B+210+%2B+10)). It's the size you set it your own CSS.

Comment: Related: [The Box Model](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/646/the-box-model#t=201612051517101504729)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Completely ignore the margin for now. How do I set 210x297mm in CSS as the size of my document? That's my question. My question was never "How do I prevent margin from scaling the size of my site" (which you can prevent with box-sizing).

Comment: @MortenMoulder - none taken. You'd have to (and as I see, have already had occasion to) ask Alvaro that. But as is obvious - the mental model I had matched Alvaro's. Namely 10mm margin + 190mm content + 10mm margin = 210mm total width. At least when using the winapi from C to size the HBITMAP of the printer's HDC, one doesn't include the margins in the page-size. You need to subtract them from the PPI * totalWidth - that is to say, the available page width is generally about 190mm. ;) PDF simplifies the task enormously, which is why I use it - it's far simpler and above all else, _consistent_

Comment: @enhzflep PDF is also something you can just do with PHP, while this isn't something I can do with HTML and CSS ;)

Comment: @MortenMoulder - yep. Precisely why I wrote a low-level class from scratch in PHP to deal with it. When outputting student's timetables, we couldn't be sure of their printers nor the individual margin settings. It was a far simpler and more elegant solution to produce documents that were the same for everyone. Sure, we'd show an HTML one for screen-use, but offer a pdf for the purposes of printing. This is going back 7-8 years now, I visited this question as a lazy way of checking the current state of affairs - far too lazy to search for what is only an idle curiosity to me.

Answer (score 0):

Some printers have default settings that can be set to print without edges. Try to look at printers settings when you try to print again. It has nothing to do with css all the time.

Comment: The issue is not that it's being cut off. As I also stated, I have removed all the default margins and padding, meaning that the top left of my page is actually the top left of the printed document as well (minus the margins when actually printing).